# sonarqube 5.0 .net analysis error

Tags: .net, sonarqube

We are using: `SonarQube` 5.0, `MSBuild Sonar Runner` 1.1 C# plugin 4.4, `jdk` 1.8

While running the analysis with FxCop Rules enabled we get the following error:

> - The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules.
> - This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see:
>     http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.
> - If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".

What I've done:

- I have installed `fxcop` 10.0.we are Using in `windows server 2008 R2`, we are not using any database.
- My major concern is if I deactivate all my `fxcop` rules then my sonar works.But if I activate then I get the above error.

Questions:

- What should I do after installing `FXcop`? I mean to tell what are the extra configuration need to be done If I want my sonar to run with `fxcop`.
- When there is sonar-runner 2.4 where can I setup `MS-build scanner` to analyse .net? kindly tell me what must be set in sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly= ?, Iam confused here.
- Do we need to install `VS2010` or other? Do we need to install any VS plugins?

Answer (score 0):

First off, unless you **can't** update the C# plugin first to `4.5+` for any weird reason, **do update** MSBuild Sonar runner to version `2.0+` before doing anything else.

Second, if you installed MSBuild Sonar Runner following this [guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), I suppose you have MSBuild installed (either by installing Visual Studio >= 2013 or by installing the latest Microsoft Build Tools - currently it is [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)).

Now let me try to answer your questions in the order you asked them:

1. > What should I do after installing `FXcop`? I mean to tell what are the extra configuration need to be done If I want my sonar to run with `fxcop`.

With the C# plugin `4.5`, Fxcop comes natively (but you need to have MSbuild `12.0` - which comes preinstalled with VS2013 - but better get the latest if possible. All you have to do is enable the Fxcop rules in SonarQube Quality profile rules, and MSBuild will pick them up automatically during build and analysis. There is no need to set `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly` for every project.

2. > When there is sonar-runner 2.4 where can I setup `MS-build scanner` to analyse .net? kindly tell me what must be set in sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly= ?, Iam confused here.

You only need MSbuild Sonar Runner installed, as that will delegate the analysis to sonar runner automatically. Please read this [guide](http://www.sonarqube.org/easy-analysis-of-visual-studio-solutions-with-the-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild/) for further clarifications. Regarding the last part of your question, see my answer below at question 1.

3. > Do we need to install `VS2010` or other? Do we need to install any VS plugins?

I suggest you install Visual Studio 2013+ to get much better result. And you need that to get MSBuild, which has it's standalone installer as well. Therefore no need to install Visual Studio at all.

---

Hope that answers all your questions and clears all doubts.